# Login system like Disqus for Twitter and Facebook

Tags: facebook, twitter

How do they manage to get user to login to Twitter / Facebook through Javascript so smoothly?

I am trying to replicate it for the web app. Basically, the user only needs to add a javascript snippet to their site to kickstart but I am clueless as to how to integrate facebook and twitter connect seamlessly.

Do they store access tokens after successfully authenticating a user?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is yes, they store access tokens after successfully authenticating a user.

After you try [facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/) and [twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/) apis, you'll see that, they both returns ids for every user who succesfully logged-in through your application. You can then simply add those ids pairing with the platform they logged in to your database. You can then use that data to track users easily.

You need to

- Create applications on both platforms
- Have pages for each provider to check if user performed a succesful login

  - Check if user is a newcomer and add that user to your database if so.
  - Set a session or cookie variable of user's local id in your own application or do whatever you are normally doing to track if a user logged-in as that user is your local user.